# How can I get a Navigation Drawer to open al WebView link?

Tags: android, webview

I'm new into Android programming.

I'm developing a simple app that has a Navigation Drawer and a WebView showing my website.

I want the Navigation to open a new link on the WebView for each option, but I don't know where to begin...

Here is a screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGnB6.png

My code (MainActivity.java):

```
implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {


/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */


private CharSequence mTitle;
private WebView mWebView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));


    // INI AGREGADO
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    // Activamos Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // Url que carga la app (webview)
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.lfcchile.com");
    // Forzamos el webview para que abra los enlaces internos dentro de la la APP
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    // Forzamos el webview para que abra los enlaces externos en el navegador
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

}

@Override
// Detectar cuando se presiona el botón de retroceso
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
// FIN AGREGADO

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
        case 4:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}
```

Comment: is this website running javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your webView contained? It should to be contained in XML: R.layout.fragment_main

The idea is following: 
1) You have XML R.layout.activity_main with only container for your fragments.
2) Your fragment, when it init, put/replace into that container by this operation:

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
        .commit();
```

3) Your fragment should have self XML with initialization

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

where R.layout.fragment_main is XML for your fragment

so put your webView initialization into that block

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
 // INI AGREGADO
mWebView = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
// Activamos Javascript
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
// Url que carga la app (webview)
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.lfcchile.com");
// Forzamos el webview para que abra los enlaces internos dentro de la la APP
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
// Forzamos el webview para que abra los enlaces externos en el navegador
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
return rootView;
```

}

How to open new link in the new fragment?
1) you can create collection with links and get link from collection by fragment position
2) BEST WAY: put link into bundle - object and set this bundle as argument of fragment before transaction commit and just final Bundle arguments = getArguments() into fragment.